# opencart payments get cancelled through paypal

Tags: paypal, opencart

Helo I am currently using opencart version 1.5.1 on a website and when a customer makes a payment through paypal, the transaction appears as cancelled and then is sent as pending to paypal.

Can anyone please explain what I can to do resolve this?

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you set up the correct statuses in the admin panel under `EXTENSIONS > PAYMENTS > PAYPAL STANDARD`? If they're all set to cancelled, that would explain this

Answer (score 0):

In admin panel Paypal checkout section, there is a of tab order status. Here you can set order status after processing.